# Avoid using global variable in Java 8 stream reduce method

Tags: java, algorithm, functional-programming, java-8, reduce

I am trying to use Java 8 to rewrite the implementation of [Moore’s Voting Algorithm](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/majority-element/) to find the Majority Element in an array.

The Java 7 implementation will be something like this:

```
public int findCandidate(int[] nums) {

    int maj_index = 0, count = 1;
    for(int i=1; i<nums.length;i++){
        if(count==0){
            count++;
            maj_index=i;
        }else if(nums[maj_index]==nums[i]){
            count++;
        } else {
            count--;
        }
    }
    return nums[maj_index];
}
```

The method I can think of is using stream reduce to get the final result

```
public int findCandidate(int[] nums) {
    int count = 1;
    Arrays
            .asList(nums)
            .stream()
            .reduce(0, (result, cur) -> {
                if (count == 0) {
                    result = cur;
                    count++;
                } else if (result == cur){
                    count++;
                } else {
                    count --;
                }
            });
    return result;
}
```

But this method have compile error, besides, it also break the functional purist, I encounter this situation many times, so what is the best way to deal with the global variable inside the lambda expression.

Comment: You may want to use mutable objects instead of primitives but this is not really the goal while using lambda expressions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So just like I told you within my comment, it is not ok to use mutable objects within your lambda expressions. But in your case, if you really want to apply the same algorithm, it'll be difficult.

Here's one that will do the same as what you want, if no majority is found, it returns `-1`

```
public static int findCandidate(int ... nums) {
    Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map =
    Arrays.stream(nums)
          .boxed()
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x));
    int value = 
          map
          .entrySet().stream()
          .max((e1, e2) -> Integer.compare(e1.getValue().size(), e2.getValue().size()))
          .map(e -> e.getKey())
          .get();
    int result = map.get(value).size();
    return result > nums.length / 2 ? value : -1;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

[Yassin Hajaj's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38547754/1441122) shows some pretty good streams techniques. (+1) Fundamentally I think it's using the right approach. There are a couple of minor improvements that can be made to it, though.

The first change is use the `counting()` collector to count the items in each group instead of accumulating them into a list. Since we're looking for a majority, all we need is the count, not the actual elements, and we avoid having to compare the lengths of the lists.

The second change is to filter the list looking for a group whose count is a majority. By definition there can be at most one, so we just filter the map entries using this predicate and terminate the stream with `findAny` instead of `max`.

The third change is to have the function return `OptionalInt` which more closely matches its intent. The `OptionalInt` either contains the majority value, or it's empty if there isn't a majority value. This avoids having to use a sentinel value such as `-1` that might actually occur in the data. Since `findAny` returns an `OptionalInt`, we're done.

Finally, I've relied on static imports in several places. This is mainly a matter of style, but I think it cleans up the code a bit.

Here's my variation:

```
static OptionalInt majority(int... nums) {
    Map<Integer, Long> map =
        Arrays.stream(nums)
              .boxed()
              .collect(groupingBy(x -> x, counting()));

    return map.entrySet().stream()
              .filter(e -> e.getValue() > nums.length / 2)
              .mapToInt(Entry::getKey)
              .findAny();
}
```

Comment: @LalitRao Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here is that Java streams don't have a true [list fold operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)).  With a true fold operation it's not too difficult to write the function as a left fold.  For example, in Haskell:

```
import Data.List (foldl')

-- A custom struct to represent the state of the fold.
data MooreState a = MooreState { candidate :: a, count :: !Int }

findCandidate :: Eq a => [a] -> Maybe a
findCandidate (first:rest) = Just result
    where 
      Moore result _ = foldl' combiner (MooreState first 1) rest                       

      combiner :: Eq a => MooreState a -> a -> MooreState a
      combiner (Moore candidate count) current
          | count == 0           = MooreState current 1
          | candidate == current = MooreState candidate (count + 1)
          | otherwise            = MooreState candidate (count - 1)

-- The empty list has no candidates.
findCandidate [] = Nothing
```

Java's `reduce()` methods are the closest it has to a true left fold, but if you look at [the Javadoc for the `reduce()` method that you're using](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-T-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-), you'll note that it says that:

1. It "is not constrained to execute sequentially";
2. It requires the accumulation function to be **associative**.

This documentation is really hard to interpret, but the way I read it is this.  Even though it might process elements out of order:

- **If** your accumulation function is associative **then** it is guaranteed to produce the same result as if you processed the stream sequentially;
- If your accumulation function is not associative, then it may produce results different from the simple sequential process.

Why is this important?  Well, first of all, the fact that you are mutating an external variable means that the way you're using the `count` is broken.  Element #7 of the stream may be processed before element #5, for all you know.

More insidiously, the `combine` operation in the Haskell version above combines inputs of different types (`Moore a` and `a`), but the Java `reduce` method that you use is based on a `BinaryOperator<T>`, which combines two objects of the same type.  There's [another overload of `reduce` that uses a `BiFunction<U, T, U>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-U-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-), but that requires you to supply a `BinaryOperator<U> combiner` and its `U identity` as well.  This is because Java's `reduce` methods are designed so that they can:

1. Split the input stream into contiguous chunks;
2. Process multiple chunks in parallel;
3. Combine the results of adjacent chunks in order when they finish.

So the associativity and identity requirements are there to guarantee that this parallel processing produces the same result as if you did it sequentially.  But this means that while there's a straightforward functional implementation of the algorithm, there is no straightforward way to write it with Java's `Stream` type.  (There is a non-straightforward way, but that gets into a bit of wizardry that would be (a) really convoluted and (b) really slow in Java.)

So I personally would just accept that Java's not a great functional programming language, leave good enough alone and use the imperative version as-is.  But if for some weird reason I really insisted on doing it functionally, I'd go for a library like [jOOλ](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOL) which provides [true left folds in Java](http://www.jooq.org/products/jOO%CE%BB/javadoc/0.9.7/index.html?overview-summary.html).  Then you can do the same as the Haskell solution (untested pseudocode):

```
import org.jooq.lambda.Seq;
import org.jooq.lambda.tuple.Tuple2;

class MooreState<A> {
    private final A candidate;
    private final int count;
    // ...constructors and getters...
}

public static Optional<A> findCandidate(Seq<A> elements) {
    Tuple2<Optional<A>, Seq<A>> split = elements.splitAtHead();
    return split.v1().map(first -> {
        Seq<A> rest = split.v2();
        return rest.foldLeft(
            new MooreState<>(first, 1),
            (state, current) -> {
                if (state.getCount() == 0) {
                    return new MooreState<>(current, 1);
                } else if (state.getCandidate().equals(current) {
                    return new MooreState<>(state.getCandidate(),
                                            state.getCount() + 1);
                } else {
                    return new MooreState<>(state.getCandidate(),
                                            state.getCount() - 1);
                }
            }
        );
    });
}
```

...which is probably terrifyingly slow.

Answer (score 0):

@Stuart Marks wrote the concise code. however it's still can simplified by [abacus-common](https://github.com/landawn/abacus-common)

```
Stream.from(nums).groupBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting())
     .findAny(e -> e.getValue() > nums.length / 2)
```

Disclosure： I'm the developer of abacus-common.